# vert.x is there a limit of Event Bus in terms of scaling

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

Trying to understand the limits of `EventBus` in the `Vert.x`.

There are Vert.x instance that is running in **cluster mode**, so there are multiple Verticles running over several physical machines. Say we have 2 machines with 10 verticles each.

So, in numbers:
1 `Vert.x` instance in cluster mode
20 Verticles instances (10 per machine)
2 machines,
1 `Event Bus`

1000 000 connections per second comes to event bus, and handled back to the verticles.

If 2 machines are not enough I still can get 100 machines, but:

From my understanding the Event Bus (EB) is **bottle neck** here? Since EB is a "communication tube" and because it is **one** for many, I imagine it will start collection all that **noise** of all events coming to it (address -> service, pub-sub etc), plus it operates in between the nodes, will it come to NET communication overhead? How do I scale the EB? Should I care about it? (or `Hazelcast` cluster should take care of all this ?)

Should I consider creating N clusters with 1 Instance of `Vert.x` in cluster mode with 10 verticles on 100 machines?

**Q:** To put in simple question, is there a limit of `Event Bus` in terms of scaling and should I consider creating infrastructure with N-buses to make sure my system is properly scaled?

(haven't done yet my tests on it..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the clustered EventBus, two things happen:

1. Vert.x creates TCP connections between the nodes registered in the cluster
2. The cluster manager keeps track of EventBus message handlers (a multimap mapping an EventBus address to node identifiers)

Then, if you *send* a message (point to point), Vert.x will pick up a handler from the cluster manager and use the TCP connection to send it to the remote node.

Or if you *publish* a message (publish/subscribe), Vert.x will send the message to all nodes having at least one handler for it (it's the responsibility of the receiving node to deliver the message to all local handlers).

So there are two "limits" to the clustered EventBus scalability: the size of the multimap (growing with the number of addresses and handlers) and the network bandwith.

It's impossible to determine without testing of course, but on modern hardware and a decent network, you should be able to deploy a 100 nodes clusters using a fixed number of addresses.